# Inbuilt PhantomJs with php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, macos, phantomjs

I want inbuilt PhantomJS with php. And how I can scrap dynamically generated data using PhantomJS. Is it possible, it is run in web services for android? And Don't have `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` in Downloaded files.

Comment: Open-ended "How to" questions are difficult to answer, and tend to generate follow-up discussions. To improve your chances of getting a helpful answer, [edit] your question to provide greater focus on the specific problem you're facing. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

you need to run this as a service on the server, for example:

```
//script.js
console.log("Hello World");
phantom.exit(0);
```

php: (linux example:)

```
exec("/usr/local/bin/phantomjs /user/path/to/script.js",$result,$error);
print_r($result); //"Hello World"
```

on windows give a path to phantomJS.exe file

**do not use phantom on live** , phantomJS is  slow and should be use only on background proccess (f.e [cronjob](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml))

Comment: where is this file in folder of phantomjs `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`